# I don't know that more put in expression regular with preg_match() in php

Tags: php, html-parsing

this copy as such of a web but I don't doing that show the value within div :/

```
<div style="float:left;">
    CARRERA 7H BIS No. 76 - 0 ALFONSO  II                                                                               
</div>

preg_match('|<div style="float:left;">(.*+)</div>|is' , $data , $cap );
echo "direccion: ".$cap[1].'<br>';
```

Comment: And where is the php code?

Comment: Simple. Don't use regex. feed your html to DOM and get the div's contents from there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Sorry, this is $data = file_get_contents("www.....");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data= '<div style="float:left;">CARRERA 7H BIS No. 76 - 0 ALFONSO  II    </div>';
preg_match('%<div style="float:left;">(.*?)<\/div>%si', $data , $cap );
echo "direccion: ".$cap[1].'<br>';
```

So, you was close, but you didn't escaped closing div - that was problem. P.S. And capturing group regex was false - this one should work. At the end 's' modifier is added - in case that new lines are in input ($data).

Updated regex for direccion:

```
$regex="%<div style='float:left;'>(.*?)<\/div>%si";
preg_match($regex, $data , $cap );
echo "direccion: ".$cap[1].'<br>';
```

Comment: Send example of data you got... Without it - we can just guess. This regex works on  example from your question (tested).

Comment: That's better - and you need: Departamento:  CAUCA
Municipio:  TIMBIO
Puesto:  PUESTO CABECERA MUNICIPAL
Dirección Puesto:  
I.E. CONC ESC GUILLERMO VALENC
Fecha de inscripción:  Jan 2 2014 10:37AM
Mesa  42

i guess? P.S. - there are no double quotes there...